# VSCode intellisense appears if only space bar pressed in Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, visual-studio-code

I'm using VSCode to develop Flutter Apps, but, intellisense only shows up when I press space bar first.

For instance when I create any widget within the widget tree, such as IconButton(icon:), the property 'icon' doesn't show up in intellisense when typing the first characters, like 'ic', only if I press the space bar, or after the property was completely typed and then if it is removed, the next time when typing, then the intellisense works fine.

Does anyone else having the same issue? it is something configurable within VSCode? or a flutter plugin bug?

Comment: I think there is no plugin for this kind of problem. Generally it happens a lot for me too when I am developing Angular apps and then I just press CTRL+SPACEBAR which activates Intellisense. This problem happens for me only when a lot of background processes are running in my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the date, I think you probably hit one of these issues:

- https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1374
- https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1378
- https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/1379

These are all fixed, so if you still have this issue on the latest version of the Dart extension then this is a bug that you should raise [on GitHub](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues) and I would be happy to take a look.