# VSCode not showing function parameter list in Dart code

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

When I edit JavaScript code, VSCode immediately show me a popup with a list of parameters as soon as I have typed a function name followed by (.

When editing Dart code this is not the case. Here I have to use the mouse to hover over the function name to show a popup with information about the function.

Is this normal behaviour? Are there any way to change this behaviour? Does anyone know a shortcut to show the popup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode dart code auto completion doesn't work properly for packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56730930/vscode-dart-code-auto-completion-doesnt-work-properly-for-packages)

Comment: Apparently, there are many duplicates to this issue already. See this one also, which references issues with Dart-Code (the relevant addon for VSCode) that might be relevant as well: [VSCode intellisense appears if only space bar pressed in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52911456/vscode-intellisense-appears-if-only-space-bar-pressed-in-flutter)

Comment: Hi Boaz. Thanks for your comments. This is not the same issues. Actually intellisense works fine for me. I just wish that the popup with information about the function would pop up automatically as it does when editing JavaScript. When editing Dart code, I need to use the mouse to hover over the function name to get any information about the parameters :-(. But this is probably "by design".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is controlled by a VS Code user setting in the Dart extension (`dart.triggerSignatureHelpAutomatically`). It's not on by default because there are [some quirks](https://dartcode.org/releases/v2-17/#v2171-2018-08-04) (that I don't remember exactly off the top of my head).

There's work in progress to move the extension to using the LSP protocol which will push some of this functionality into the Dart analysis server, which may make it easier to make some functionality like this more reliable (since more info is available in the language server than is currently exposed to the VS Code extension).

Comment: Hi Danny. Thanks a lot. What a valuable answer. Spot on. I have tried out the setting and yes, there are some quirks. Actually it seems quite random. But by googling the setting I found out that you can always activate the signature help by pressing CTRL+SHIFT+SPACE, which is very valuable.